# DatabaseReference not being fetched from Firestore

Tags: java, database, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display the following information from my **FireStore** Database
[image]
For a given user (current user) I want to display their 'matches'(other user's id and information)
I also tried with a different structure by having an array of matches (user id strings) inside each user.
This is what I am trying:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_matches);
        currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        System.out.println("current user is: "+currentUserID);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
//      mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mMatchesLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MatchesActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mMatchesLayoutManager);
        mMatchesAdapter = new MatchesAdapter(getDataSetMatches(), MatchesActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMatchesAdapter);
        getUserMatchId();

    }
private void getUserMatchId() {
    DatabaseReference matchDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(currentUserID).child("connections").child("matches");
    matchDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot match : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    System.out.println(match.toString());
                    FetchMatchInformation(match.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
private void FetchMatchInformation(String key) {
    DatabaseReference userDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(key);
    userDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String userId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                String name = "";
                String profileIMageUrl = "";
                if(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()!=null){
                    name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue()!=null){
                    profileIMageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().toString();
                }
                MatchesObject obj = new MatchesObject(userId, name, profileIMageUrl);
                resultsMatches.add(obj);
                mMatchesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<MatchesObject> resultsMatches = new ArrayList<>();

private List<MatchesObject> getDataSetMatches() {
    return resultsMatches;
}
```

I tried debugging the code for a little bit and I realized that after adding the listener to matchDB nothing happens
It'd be great if you could tell me why nothing is being displayed and how to access the matches properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) (which stores data in collections and documents) but using the code for [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) (which stores data in a large JSON like format) to make your query.

To use Firestore, make sure you have these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')

    // Declare the dependency for the Cloud Firestore library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
}
```

Then you can try running this code to query from Firestore:

```
firestore.collection("users").document(currentUserID).collection("connections")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

It should log IDs of all documents present in connections collection. This code right above works if you actually store an individual document for each connection rather than storing all IDs in an array in a document called matches. If you use a single document for storing a lot of IDs you may exceed the 1 MB limit of a document.